# Something that grows faster than NP class of problem does

Tags: exponentiation, exponential-function

I have a theoretical question. F.ex. we have a NP-class of problem, i.e. which do need exponential time on deterministic Turing machine. Is there anything that is growing faster than exponent does. Even if it would be just some theoretical concept. And if such concept is possible to exist, may it exist f.ex. a problem that do correspond to this class.

Comment: Tetration is faster than exponential: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration

Answer (score 0):

Finding a [Hamilton Path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) for example is in NEXPTIME, and it is known that $NP \subsetneq NEXPTIME$. More preceisly, it can be solved by a nondeterministic Turing machine using time $O(2^p(x))$, where p(x) is a polynomial. A very nice reference is [Aaronsons Complexity Zoo](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo).

Comment: Thank you! And what is the most expensive algorithmic task discovered on present time? Is there anything bigger than NEXPTIME?